# Force closes caused by onClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, onclicklistener

I made just one `activity` that opens another `activity`. Everything was working right until i setted up onClickListener. Now my app force closes when it launch. Without these two lines application launches correctly:

```
BUeasycounter.setOnClickListener(this);
BUrps.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Here is my full source:

```
package com.dano.learning;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Menu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button BUeasycounter;
    Button BUrps;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle MyBundle) {
        super.onCreate(MyBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeVars();
// next 2 lines cause the problem
        BUeasycounter.setOnClickListener(this);
        BUrps.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void initializeVars(){
        Button BUeasycounter= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BUeasycounter);
        Button BUrps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BUrps);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.BUeasycounter:
                Intent openEasyCounter = new Intent("com.dano.learning.EASYCOUNTER");
                startActivity(openEasyCounter);
                break;
            case R.id.BUrps:
                Intent openRPS = new Intent("com.dano.learning.EASYCOUNTER");
                startActivity(openRPS);
                break;
        };

    }
}
```

Maybe i just typed something wrong but I cant find mistake in my source for more than two days. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have to provide more information. A stacktrace would be helpfully. Probably there is a NullPointer somewhere in the onClick method.

Comment: Post your logcat of the crash.

Comment: It's very useful to help you debug if there's a LogCat/StackTrace in your post.  If you don't know where that information can be found, it's a question worth asking.

Comment: You aren't using the same instance of your buttons. You are using local buttons in `initializeVars` and global vars in onCreate. Move the `setOnClickListener` call to `initializeVars()` and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exception stack in question, but based on code I see one issue is:

```
    Button BUeasycounter;
    Button BUrps;
```

Both are pointing to `null` which could be throwing `NullPointerException` when you do

```
    BUeasycounter.setOnClickListener(this);
    BUrps.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Remove new variable in `initializeVars` method.

Example:

```
public void initializeVars(){
          BUeasycounter= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BUeasycounter);
          BUrps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BUrps);
    }
```

Note: Java naming convention suggest that use small letter as first letter for variable name.

Answer (score 1):

remove smi-colon after swich case :

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.BUeasycounter:
                Intent openEasyCounter = new Intent("com.dano.learning.EASYCOUNTER");
                startActivity(openEasyCounter);
                break;
            case R.id.BUrps:
                Intent openRPS = new Intent("com.dano.learning.EASYCOUNTER");
                startActivity(openRPS);
                break;
        } //>>>> from here remove semi-colon
```

and change `initializeVars` method as :

```
  public void initializeVars(){
          BUeasycounter= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BUeasycounter);
          BUrps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BUrps);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void initializeVars(){
    Button BUeasycounter= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BUeasycounter);
    Button BUrps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BUrps);
}
```

You define two button in this method but these are local variable whose scope lies between this block.
You can not access outside from this. You have initialize the local variable but instance button variable
still have null.To get solution from NPE you should write as

```
public void initializeVars(){
    BUeasycounter= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BUeasycounter);
    BUrps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BUrps);
}
```

From above method it assign the reference in instance variable its scope till this class exist.
and last remove semi colon from end of switch block.